# Sonar tests and binaries properties, what do they do?

Tags: ant, properties, sonarqube

In Sonar documentation there are two properties options, the `sonar.tests` and `sonar.binaries`.

```
# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=testDir1,testDir2

# path to project binaries (optional), for example directory of Java bytecode
sonar.binaries=binDir
```

Questions:

1. If `sonar.tests` and `sonar.binaries` are added to my Ant target, how do they show up in Sonar? What would be different in Sonar if I did/did not set these properties?
2. Should `sonar.binaries` contain both source binaries and test binaries, or only source?
3. Can .jar files be given to both properties instead of path to actual .class files and/or .java files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers:

1. If you do not set those 2 properties, you won't have test results ("sonar.tests") nor violations detected by Findbugs or bytecode-based tools ("sonar.binaries").
2. "sonar.binaries" should contain only compiled sources, not tests
3. No. Only "sonar.libraries" can (and actually must) point to JAR files.